# Is a web2py project typically made up of multiple applications?

Tags: python, web, web2py

web2py beginner. In django, a project is typically made up of multiple applications that encapsulate project functions, right? Do web2py projects typically have the same structure or is the entire website just a single application?

Comment: Varies according to scope & size of the project.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, a website is probably a single web2py application, though that doesn't have to be the case (a web2py installation can include multiple applications, which can interact with each other). An application itself can be composed of multiple re-usable plugins (similar to how a Django project can be made up of multiple apps). Each application typically has its own database (or even multiple databases) and sessions, though both databases and sessions can be shared across applications if desired.